# How can I add a startup class for IoC registration in an WCF application?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, inversion-of-control, startup

I have the following four projects:

```
Service.WCFApplication
    -> References
        -> Service.WCFLibrary
    MainService.svc 

Service.WCFLibrary
    -> References
        -> Service.WCFModels
        -> Domain.BusinessLogic
    IMainService.cs
    MainService.cs

Service.WCFModels
    -> Models 
        GetTestRequest
        GetTestResponse   

Domain.BusinessLogic
```

The Service.WCFLibrary contains all `ServiceContract` and Implementation.
As an example the IMainService.cs:

```cs
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMainService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    GetTestResponse GetTest(GetTestRequest request);
}
```

And MainService.cs as an implementation of the interface:

```cs
public class MainService : IMainService
{
    public GetTestResponse GetTest(GetTestRequest request);
    {
        //TODO: call business logic
    }
}
```

The `Service.WCFApplication` is only a wrapper of the library to host this WCF service on an IIS, so the `MainService.svc` only contains this line of code:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Service.WCFLibrary.MainService" %>
```

I would like to register my business logic with IoC, but I don't know where to find a point of entry.
I added a Startup- or Global.asax class in WCFApplication but it doesn't work.

Where can I register my business logic so that I can consume it in the WCF library?

Answer (score 2):

WCF extensibility point for DI is `IInstanceProvider` interface:

```
public interface IInstanceProvider
{
    object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext);
    object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message);
    void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance);
}
```

But usually you don't need to implement it by yourself. There are existing implementations for common DI containers.

For example [Unity.WCF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Wcf/) for Unity. Here is detailed [article](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/introducing-unity.wcf-providing-easy-ioc-integration-for-your-wcf-services) how to integrate Unity container it in WCF application.

There are implementations for Castle Windsor, Autofac, etc. Just google and you will find the articles how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use conventions.You can create a folder named `App_Startup` in your `Service.WCFLibrary`. In this folder you created a startup class like this:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    private ServiceContainer serviceContainer;

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        this.serviceContainer = new ServiceContainer();
        serviceContainer.Register<ISomething, Something>();
        //etc...
    }
}
```

In your `Service.WCFApplication` you can create a folder named `App_Code` with file `Initializer.cs` like this:

```cs
public class Initializer
{
    private ServiceContainer serviceContainer;

    public static void AppInitialize()
    {
        this.serviceContainer = new ServiceContainer();
        serviceContainer.Register<ISomething, Something>();
        //etc...
    }
}
```